# Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve "expo-barcode-scanner"

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm implementing a system on my APP React native using the expo and the function is basically to turn the wifi on and off the device. For that I am adding the following library: react-native-android-wifi. I installed everything as the library says more when I call the library it returns this error in my app.

I'm importing this way:

```
import wifi from 'react-native-android-wifi';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This library is not currently compatible with Expo. So I suggest that you eject your project.